# Restore multipliers from the product

Tags: set-theory

Let $f$ and $g$ are binary relations (on some set $\mho$). The function $f\times^{C} g$ is defined by the formula: $(f\times^{C} g) a = g\circ a \circ f^{-1}$ (for every binary relation $a$ on $\mho$.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are non-empty. Can we restore $f$ and $g$ knowing only the value of $f\times^{C} g$?

Comment: When you say, "knowing only the value of $f \times^C g$", do you mean you can feed any binary relation into this construction and you'll know the resulting binary relation? 

Comment: @Hugh Denoncourt: We should feed only values arising as a $\times^C$ product of some binary relations $f$ and $g$ (It seems that there are values which $f\times^C g$ cannot take. We don't consider these values.)

Once more: We know $f\times^C g$ and that it is non-empty. We need to infer $f$ and $g$.

Comment: A more difficult question continuing this trend:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101576/a-special-product-of-filters-on-direct-products-of-sets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a_{u,v} = \{(u,v)\}$.  Then $g\circ a_{u,v}\circ f^{-1} = f^{-1}(u)\times g(v)$.  Assuming $g$ is nonempty, pick $v\in \text{dom}(g)$.  Then $\text{dom} \left[(f\times^C g)a_{u,v}\right] = f^{-1}(u)$, so varying $u$ allows you to recover $f$.  Similarly picking $u\in\text{range}(f)$ and varying $v$ you can recover $g$.